# Why do Famous Philosophers not provide bibliographies and references?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Famous philosophers such as Kant or Heidegger were also academic philosophers. In my (limited) experience its standard practise that academics provide a bibliography/references to ground their text. However, it seems that the famous philosophers don't do this, unless the texts which I've seen, mostly online, have had this exercised.

Is this actually the case? Does a secondary literature provide the sources that the Famous Philosophers neglect to provide themselves? Or is the standard practise of bibliographies a relatively recent innovation?

Comment: For starters, some philosophers don't need to provide a bibliography because they don't use one. Kant for example builds (almost?) his whole system from scratch, doesn't he?

Comment: Bibliographies as we imagine them now are mostly an idea that starts in the 20th century... Can you narrow your question in some way?

Comment: I think the question, as standing in the headline, is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @virmaior:you've answered my question; its not really worth improving

Comment: It's not only philosophers' papers lacking references. See for instance Einstein's papers from 1905.